# How can I perform 301 url redirection in Magento 2.0?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, url-rewrite, .htaccess, 301-redirect

URL structure has been changed for one of product page in my Magento 2.0 webstore. Now I need to perform 301 redirection to newly created URL.

Is `.htaccess` still helpful here? If yes then please share code snippets or else suggest new technique.